# Mongo server not starting by cmd mongod --dbpath /Users/mayankpatel/data/db

Tags: database, mongodb, macos, installation, homebrew

I have installed mongo through homebrew but when I try to run the cmd:

```
--dbpath /Users/mayankpatel/data/db
```

It gives me following error instead of starting mongo server:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.852+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.854+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.854+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.854+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":5684,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/Users/mayankpatel/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Mayanks-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.854+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.3","gitVersion":"913d6b62acfbb344dde1b116f4161360acd8fd13","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.854+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"19.6.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.854+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"storage":{"dbPath":"/Users/mayankpatel/data/db"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.855+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.855+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":10000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.855+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.855+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.855+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.855+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.855+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.855+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.855+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.855+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.855+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.855+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.855+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-26T08:36:11.855+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":48}}
```

*Note: I am using MacOS.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error - `Address already in use` means MongoDB is already running.

```
Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}
```

You've to close the previous running mongo server, you can find by using `ps -aux | grep mongo`

After that, you can `kill -9 processId` eg- `kill -9 2781`

Comment: I tried to kill those process running on port 27017 via kill -9 <PID> and again ran the command but it didnt work.

Comment: Same error even after killing the process.

Comment: @MayankPatel Can you please elaborate on the error?

Comment: @MayankPatel Did you get any `ps -aux | grep mongo` process running?

Comment: @MayankPatel, you could also do 1st- use `ps -ef | grep mongo` to get pid of mongodb process once you get it(2nd field in its Output by the way). Then do a `netstat -aonp | grep your_mongo_pid_here` which will give you either its listening on port or not, please follow these steps and get back to us how it goes, cheers.